# Is the discrepancy in universe expansion in the speed of expansion, the rate that the speed is changing or both?

Tags: classical-mechanics, optics, gravity, visible-light, cosmology

Is there a simpler way to describe the latest discrepancies or problem with the expansion of the universe. Does the rate of expansion consistently get faster and faster? I was reading this and had some questions. https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2019/07/debate-intensifies-over-speed-expanding-universe

Comment: "*Is there a simpler way to describe the latest discrepancies or problem with the expansion of the universe*"? - The accelerating expansion is an interpretation based on the assumed FLRW geometry of the universe. However, the FLRW model is obviously incorrect, because it grossly mismatches observations. In particular, it mismatches the observed matter content in the universe by no less than 95%. This model also contradicts General Relativity and requires a modified gravity with a "cosmological constant" added to the field equations for no other reason, but to make a bad model look better.

Answer (score 0):

The modified Big Bang is the mainstream cosmological models and it describes the observations and data. Discrepancy means a comparison between old models and new models. The Big Bang resolves them.

The article you quote is talking of a discrepancy between measurements of the Hubble constant, and I have asked about it in the astronomy.se.  The resolution will have to be by finding the difference in the models that calculate the Hubble constant. I suspect, since the discrepancy between the various measured values is with the number derived from the Cosmic Microwave Radiation, which has a lot of hypothesis , thermodynamic and particle physics entering, those calculations will have to be rethought. I was asking whether the baryon asymmetry is taken into account in the CMB calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of the universe is powered by what we call Dark Energy (DE), its a sort of vacuum energy, produced in large, empty sections of the universe between any large structure. https://www.lsst.org/science/dark-energy/universe.   Hopefully that link will help some. Einstein called it the cosmological constant,  because no matter how big the universe gets, instead of becoming defuse In the huge voids, the energy density has stayed the same for around 9 billion years.
   And as to why the universe is expanding faster and faster if the force driving it, DE, is constant, its because the amount of empty space between galaxies and all other large structures is expanding. And the bigger the voids, the more space DE can expand, so the further away an structure is, the faster it moving away. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.space.com/amp/41163-universe-expansion-rate-changes-near-far.html.    much of the universe is expanding faster than the speed of light. Hope that was helpful, or at least the links can fill anything in.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is not necessarily about expansion or speed of expansion. It’s about the discrepancy between the two ways it’s measured. They do not agree exactly.